# How to make equal column height and vertical align text : middle in div using Bootstrap 3 (responsive)? Don't need display table or flex. If possible

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design, height, vertical-alignment

Can't find the solution.
I have row with two columns. One with img, and another with text.
I find the solution about equal heights two columns. Also I would like to vertical align text in div. I tried some methods, but it didn't work. Please help.. This is the image -- -
[what I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bjAIT.png)

[what I need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uL2oB.png)

Comment: can you share your code ?

Comment: you can columns equal height using jquery.

Comment: @SahilDhir https://jsfiddle.net/romansstudents/fLs47cdb/8/

Comment: Not possible without flex or display-table cell if using css..

Comment: @SahilDhir Now I see. What about jquery solution?

Answer (score 0):

This css class will make your columns height the same.
To center the image, you could use flex, `align-items: center` like in `.center-img`

```css
.row-eq-height{
    display:-webkit-box;
    display:-ms-flexbox;
    display:flex;
    border:1px solid blue;
}

div.center-img {
  border:2px solid red;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row row-eq-height">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <p>text</p>
        <p>text</p>
        <p>text</p>
        <p>text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 center-img">
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/vo8VJ.jpg?s=64&g=1" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. It works. For responsive I also add flex-wrap: wrap.